# Functional equation problem: $ f ( x ) + \frac 1 { x + 1 } = f ( x + 1 ) $

Tags: functional-equations

I've been trying to find a function that satisfies this to solve a separate problem, but I'm finding it difficult and no polynomial seems to work.

$$ f ( x ) + \frac 1 { x + 1 } = f ( x + 1 ) $$

Comment: Looks like the harmonic series to me, but I am guessing you want to extend $x$ to the reals.

Comment: You can *almost* take $\ln x$ because $\ln(x+1)-\ln x =\frac1{x+\theta}$ with $0<\theta<1$.

Comment: $f(x) = \psi(x+1)$ where $\psi(x)$ is the [Digamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digamma_function) will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(x)+\dfrac{1}{x+1}=f(x+1)$

$f(x+1)-f(x)=\dfrac{1}{x+1}$

$f(x)=\sum\limits_x\dfrac{1}{x+1}+\Theta(x)$, where $\Theta(x)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with unit period

Since $\lim\limits_{x\to+\infty}\dfrac{1}{x+1}=0$, so according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indefinite_sum#Mueller.27s_formula, the result can be further simplified to

$f(x)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\left(\dfrac{1}{n+1}-\dfrac{1}{x+n+1}\right)+\Theta(x)$, where $\Theta(x)$ is an arbitrary periodic function with unit period

Comment: It might be better to rewrite the $\sum_x$ line with dummy indices and limits, that's a little odd notationally!